# Can we get subscription id in Return URL after payment success using hosted page in recurly?

Tags: recurly

I am using recurly hosted page for billing.I would like to redirect to my site after successful payment,In return page i want subscription id.Is that possible in recurly ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to pass the subscription_id in the hosted page confirmation URL, but you can use the account_code and plan_code. That should be enough to either run a quick API query to get the sub uuid or to reference a webhook integration to get the sub uuid.

Comment: if user subscribed for multiple plan ? how would i get particular subscription ? i need to fetch all subscription order by last and than i get, is it ?

Comment: A query of the new subscription web hook will provide the subscription UUID, plan_code, account_code and other related information to recently created subscriptions.  Best practices recommend use of web hooks to trigger an api query in order to return confirmed account information on new subscriptions. Data returned in a new subscription web hook can be reviewed in our documentation at https://recurly.readme.io/v2.0/page/webhooks